# Nothing found in uploads folder after wp_insert_attachment

Tags: attachments

I'm trying to add a text file as an attachment

I first enabled the mime type

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1 );
function my_myme_types( $mime_types ) {
  $mime_types['txt'] = 'text/plain';
  return $mime_types;
}
```

After submitting the frontend post form, I send the chunk of text to the server via ajax so I can add it to a text file and then insert it as an attachment

```
function rt_new_template(){
    global $post;
    $user_id = absint($_POST["uid"]);
    $post_title = sanitize_text_field($_POST["post_title"]);
    $post_object = get_page_by_title($post_title, OBJECT, 'chat');
    $post_id = $post_object->ID;
    $msg_array = $_POST["msgArray"];
    $ext = ".txt";
    $file = $user_id . $post_title . $ext;
    // $date = date("Y/m/d");
    file_put_contents($file, $msg_array);
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $attachment = array(
        'guid'=> $wp_upload_dir['url'] .'/'. basename( $file ), 
        'post_mime_type' => 'text/plain',
        'post_title' => $user_id . $post_title,
        'post_content' => $user_id . $post_title,
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
         );

    $mid = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, $post_id);
    if ( !is_wp_error($mid) ){
       wp_update_attachment_metadata( $mid, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $mid, $file ) );
    }
    die();  
}
```

After completion I can see the newly created media file in the admin media section. It only shows a document icon in the preview section.

The URL in the preview for the file is

```
http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/224331554033108974.txt
```

But going to that address gives me a 404 and there's no text file in the uploads folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_put_contents($file, $msg_array);
```

should be

```
file_put_contents($wp_upload_dir['path'] .'/'. basename( $file ), $msg_array);
```

Comment: Does that mean I don't have to run wp_insert_attachment?

Comment: No, it does not mean that. `wp_insert_attachment` attaches your file to post/page with ID of `$post_id` and  inserts the attachment into the media library. [DOCS](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)

Comment: So that takes me to the correct URL but I still don't see the file in the folder. I'm on localhost. I've tried shutting it all down and restarting. Nothing there.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Updated the answer. Replace `'url'` with `'path'` in the code. [Ref](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/#user-contributed-notes)

Comment: What should the "guid" be then?

Comment: `guid` should be a `url`. That part of code is correct.